# Bootstrap 3 hide navbar button not working on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website with bootstrap but whenever I resize the window so that it simulates the mobile version the top navbar becomes large and the button to shrink it does not work. Also, all of the content seems to either disappear or hide behind the expanded navbar. How would I fix the navbar so that it can shrink? Also, when this is fixed, how could I add a button or functionality to shrink the  sidebar as well?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>dashboard</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Upper Merion Crew</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Rowers <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#coaches">Coaches</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Upper Merion Crew</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Rowers <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#coaches">Coaches</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

      <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1,001</td>
              <td>Lorem</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>dolor</td>
              <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the placement of your list items in the navbar.

The `<ul>` has to be inside the  `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">`

Currently it is outside the div.

Check this working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggrrxfs2/1/)**